# PowerShell FTP copy only if larger

Tags: powershell, ftp

I'm using PowerShell to FTP my site backups to my local server, but I only want to copy the file if: (1) the file doesn't exist -- this works, or (2) the source file is larger. Sometimes the FTP will fail and leave a smaller file in the destination, and when it re-runs, I'd like it to overwrite the incomplete file. The script I have only copies the file if it doesn't exist in the destination. How can I modify this script to look at the source file size and copy it if the source is larger than the destination file? Thank you!

```
$ftp = "ftp://myserver" 
$user = 'username' 
$pass = 'password'
$folder = 'site_backups'
$target = "C:\Backups"

#SET CREDENTIALS
$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

function Get-FtpDir ($url,$credentials) {
    $request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
    if ($credentials) { $request.Credentials = $credentials }
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream() 
    $reader.ReadToEnd()
    $reader.Close()
    $response.Close()
}

#SET FOLDER PATH
$folderPath= $ftp + "/" + $folder + "/"

$Allfiles=Get-FTPDir -url $folderPath -credentials $credentials
$files = ($Allfiles -split "`r`n")

$files 

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 
$counter = 0
foreach ($file in ($files | where {$_ -like "*.*"})) {
    $source=$folderPath + $file  
    $destination = $target + $file

    Get-ChildItem $target | ForEach-Object {
    
        if(-not(Test-Path $destination)) {

            $webclient.DownloadFile($source, $target+$file)

            #PRINT FILE NAME AND COUNTER
            $counter++
            $counter
            $source
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `$file` look like?

Comment: I'm not sure I like the logic of "if larger". What if your source data is genuinely smaller than your last backed up data? Might be ideal to check the date of the file, instead.

Comment: You can use the 'Length' property of a file to determine if the one on the destination is smaller than the one you're trying to copy.
$sourceFile = ls C:\Path\To\Source.file
$dest = ls \\Path\To\Dest.file
if ($dest.Lenth -lt $sourceFile.Lenth) { <# Do stuff #> }

Comment: You could upload the file with a name "*. incomplete". When finished then rename it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies. I really like your solution @An-dir. I added .incomplete then did the rename. This gives us the validation of completion we need. Thank you!

            $webclient.DownloadFile($source, $target+$file+".incomplete")
            Rename-Item -Path $target$file.incomplete -NewName $file